# Apply specific where condition to every ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I've got a rails model: `Product < ActiveRecord::Base`

`Product` has a `deleted` column in the database that is a 0/1 flag.

Is there a way that I can make all queries on `Product` apply the where condition `WHERE deleted = 0`?

I'd like `Product.all`, `Product.includes`, etc... and any relation, like `has_many :products` to exclude "`deleted`" `Products` by default.

It'd be nice to be able to override this in a one-off query some way (so I can select deleted products deliberately).

My guess is this is not possible, but I'd love to hear otherwise!

Comment: What about `.includes(:products).where.not('products.attribute = ?' ''deleted")`

Comment: @gwalshington I'd like to apply this to all queries from the model once, rather than every time I request products

Comment: @maxhud: look into using `default_scope`

Comment: @potashin bingo - can you write that as an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`default_scope`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/default_scope) for this:

```
default_scope { where(deleted: 0) }
```